# `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production` gives error

Tags: apache-2.2, postgresql, ruby-on-rails, deployment

When I run the command: `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production` I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "1.2.3.4" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

So I guess my server is not listening on port 5432. So how do I solve this?

I tried running command: `sudo service postgresql start` but I still get that same error.

I know I have to edit some file so in addition to the instructions on how to actually edit the file (I guess it is the file named `postgresql.conf`?) please also tell me where I should find it.

My web application is on this directory at the server: /home/admin/www/webstudio

EDIT: I have already tried my best to follow the instructions given here: http://alexbachuk.com/launch-rails-4-application-with-passenger-and-nginx/

Comment: The obvious solution is to start postgresql.

Comment: Yes, I guess it is obvious :) So how do I do that? postgre -D %PATH%? I found that from one site, but I don't know the path.. What could it be? I'm a complete novice to this all so please bear with me.

Comment: I started postgresql with a command: sudo service postgresql start but it didn't help :(

Comment: Two things now: First, [don't use other people's public IP addresses in your posts](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632). Second, look at your logs and find out what's going on with postgresql.